# Python -- Unable to find element by Xpath, ID and Name

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

[image]

[image]

I just recently start to use Python, and I'm trying to input something into a search bar as shown in the picture.

I have tried Xpath, Name and ID, but none of those works. It looks pretty straight forward, but I keep receiving error messages.

I have tried:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="PRCSRUNCNTL_RUN_CNTL_ID"]')
driver.find_element_by_name("PRCSRUNCNTL_RUN_CNTL_ID")
driver.find_element_by_id("win0divPRCSRUNCNTL_RUN_CNTL_ID")
```

Error Messages for Xpath:

[image]

Comment: Please don't post pictures of code/error messages, post the text directly here on SO instead. I suggest, you edit your question.

Comment: Nothing looks off about your locators, though your XPath should specify input instead of *, since we know what type of element it is.

A couple helpful questions to ask yourself:
1. Is the element present at the time you are checking?
- Go into the console tab of your browser dev tools and type $x('//input[@id="PRCSRUNCNTL_RUN_CNTL_ID"]')
- Does it find the input?
2. Could there be a modal or iframe that is actually receiving the driver's focus?

Comment: Thanks Aphid for your reply. I tried to type the one you suggested into Console tab, but nothing seems to be found, as it shows "[]"

Comment: It seem that you're trying to select option from drop-down, but those options might appears on page only if you click on "begins with", right?

Comment: @Andersson  Thanks for your reply.  The "begins with" is the default option for that drop-down. There won't be anything comes up in the search bar when selecting the drop-down.

Comment: Oh, yep, I thought you want to handle drop-down :) Try `//*[contains(., "begins with")]/following::input[@type="text"]`

Comment: @LiuJJ if your console shows nothing ([]), then your element is currently not findable, at least not with those locators. Try this: $x("//input")   If you get a list of results, click the arrow to expand that list and hover your mouse over each entry. Do you see your desired element?

Comment: @Aphid   Yes, I see a series of input#.....   and an element called:  "input#PRCSRUNCNTL_RUN_CNTL_ID.PSEDITBOX"   should be the one I am looking for. What would be the next step?

Comment: Sounds like your ID is actually PRCSRUNCNTL_RUN_CNTL_ID.PSEDITBOX, not PRCSRUNCNTL_RUN_CNTL_ID

Comment: @Aphid , no `.PSEDITBOX` in CSS selector stands for `class="PSEDITBOX"`, so id is actually `"PRCSRUNCNTL_RUN_CNTL_ID"`

Comment: @LiuJJ, check whether required node located inside an iframe

Comment: @Andersson    I do find an "iframe" covering the entire page. something like:                                                                                                    
  <iframe id="ptifrmtgtframe" name="TargetContent" title="Main Content" frameborder="0"    ............................</iframe>  (this is the first one)                                                                                                                      <iframe name="RelatedContent" id="RelatedContent" title="Related Content" frameborder="0" ...........></iframe>       (this is the 2nd one)

Comment: @LiuJJ , ok. So it means that you should try `driver.switch_to.frame("ptifrmtgtframe")` before locating input field

Comment: @Andersson      It is working!   Thanks so much for both of you. Save my time!

Comment: @Andersson good catch, bush league mistake.

Comment: Please read why a [screenshot of HTML or code or error is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Consider updating the Question with formatted text based relevant HTML, code trials and error stack trace.